# Retrieving Data by Joining 2 DB Tables, but Table 2 row is optional

Tags: c#

```
studentlist.Add(
    new StudentViewModel
    {
        StudentName = Convert.ToString(dr["StudentName"]),
        StudentCourse = Convert.ToString(dr["StudentCourse"]),
        StudentId = Convert.ToInt32(dr["StudentId"]),
        MotherName  = dr["MotherName"] == System.DBNull.Value ? string.Empty : Convert.ToString(dr["MotherName"]),
        FatherName  = dr["FatherName"] == System.DBNull.Value ? string.Empty : Convert.ToString(dr["FatherName"])
    });
```

I have this data that is being retrieved by left joining 2 of my database tables, but table 2 entry (`MotherName` and `FatherName`) is optional. Now I'm getting an error

> Object cannot be cast from DBNull to other types

for records in table 1 that don't have corresponding record in table 2

Answer (score 0):

For nullable columns, add a check always, because as the exception message suggests, DBNull cannot be cast to other types.

```
FatherName = dr["FatherName"] == System.DBNull.Value ? string.Empty : Convert.ToString(dr["FatherName"])
```

**UPDATE**

OK, I have to correct myself. Convert.ToString() handles DBNull just fine.

I created a small sample application and even your original snippet works just fine with DBNull.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable("table");
        dt.Columns.AddRange(new[]
        {
            new DataColumn("StudentName", typeof(string)),
            new DataColumn("StudentCourse", typeof(string)),
            new DataColumn("StudentId", typeof(int)),
            new DataColumn("MotherName", typeof(string)),
            new DataColumn("FatherName", typeof(string))
        });

        dt.PrimaryKey = new[] { dt.Columns["StudentId"] };

        // Father not specified
        dt.Rows.Add("Johnny Doe, Jr.", "OfCourse", 1, "Jane Doe", DBNull.Value);
        var dr = dt.Rows.Find(1);

        var studentlist = new List<StudentViewModel>();

        // Same as you did
        studentlist.Add(
            new StudentViewModel
            {
                StudentName = Convert.ToString(dr["StudentName"]),
                StudentCourse = Convert.ToString(dr["StudentCourse"]),
                StudentId = Convert.ToInt32(dr["StudentId"]),
                MotherName = Convert.ToString(dr["MotherName"]),
                FatherName = Convert.ToString(dr["FatherName"])
            });

        foreach (var student in studentlist)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(student);
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Done");
        Console.Read();
    }

    class StudentViewModel
    {
        public string StudentName { get; set; }
        public string StudentCourse { get; set; }
        public int StudentId { get; set; }
        public string MotherName { get; set; }
        public string FatherName { get; set; }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return $"[{StudentId}] {StudentName} (Mother: {MotherName}; Father: {FatherName}) attending: {StudentCourse}";
        }
    }
}
```

It outputs:

```
[1] Johnny Doe, Jr. (Mother: Jane Doe; Father: ) attending: OfCourse
Done
```

Are you sure this is where your exception is coming from?

Comment: Error `string.Empty()` Non invocable member string.Empty cannot be used like a method

Comment: I removed the `()` in the word `Empty` an its fine now but I get again the error `Object cannot be cast from DBNull to other types`

Comment: There was a typo in it, corrected like 20 seconds after the post. But I guess I missed the window. :) And you have to do it for ALL the nullable columns to get rid of that error.

Comment: Im getting again the error "Object cannot be cast from DBNull to other types" i did it both for `MotherName` and `FatherName`

Comment: Ok, update your code sample in the post, where is the exception thrown?